# Unable to start Debugging on the web server

Tags: .net, asp.net

I am getting the error as i specified. Till yesterday it works fine for me suddenly i found this issue can any one tell what to do

[image]

Find out the image for further reference and help me in resolving this issue.

I am getting this issue for only the application which are under `Local Host`, if i have my solution in a directory it is working fine

Comment: Any help please i am strucked with this

Answer (score 2):

Please check

1. IIS App Pool that your application is running have the same .NET runtim version as your debugger is.
2. Application has

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable integrated Windows authentication to debug on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Check the asp.net version of your application in IIS and see if it matches the .NET version of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for all the three answers above. Any one of these or a combination of them can resolve your issue.

My fourth option is: run the application under Visual Studio web server 'cassini' instead of configuring it in the IIS.

Because, if you are running it under Windows 7, you will have to run VS as administrator.

5th option : delete all temp files, bin and debug files , close and open VS and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Application Pool being used by the IIS application has the correct credentials. If you're using an Application Pool with your AD account as the identity, then you will see this error whenever you change the password for your AD account.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Physical path Location,

- Go to IIS Manager
- Go to website location under the default website folder
- Go to Advanced settings and check at the Physical path Location here
- Make sure you put the location of the working folder for this application there.

Regards,
Pranay.